# Powershell script to get tag information from all Resource Groups

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, azure-resource-manager

I need to retrieve the "owner" tag that is associated to all Resource Groups for all Subscriptions in our tenant. I seem to be getting records that don't exist in the tenant. Maybe I'm going about this wrong but I thought I would iterate through all subscriptions and then iterate through all Resource groups and then go through the tag information. I get the same records for most of these resource groups. Can anyone spot the issue?

```bash
# Connect-AzAccount
$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$count = 1
foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.SubscriptionId
    Write-Host $count. $sub.Name
    $count ++
    $resource_groups = Get-AzResourceGroup
    foreach ($rg in $resource_groups) {
        Write-Host '       ' $rg.ResourceGroupName
        $rgTags = Get-AzTag -Name 'owner'
        if ($rgTags -ne $null) {
            foreach ($tag in $rgTags.Values) {
                Write-Host '               '$tag.Name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`Search-AzGraph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resourcegraph/search-azgraph?view=azps-10.2.0) to query the [Resource Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview), it's much easier and faster with KQL than it will ever be with the individual cmdlets.

The query can be read as:

> For each container in `resourcecontainers` where their type is `microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups` and their `owner` Tag is not null or empty project the properties `subscriptionId`, `resourceGroup`, `ownertag`.

```bash
Search-AzGraph -Query @'
    resourcecontainers
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups'
    | extend ownertag = tags.owner
    | where isnotempty(ownertag)
    | project subscriptionId, resourceGroup, ownertag
'@
```